# SQL Server Sub query with multiple results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to populate an existing bridge table from a table that exists as a template for how items are populated into the bridge table.

I am attempting to do a new insert into the bridge table (dbo.ECN_ChecklistItem) where the list of items from dbo.ECN_ChecklistItem (SELECTed by ECNID (a foreign key ID)) differs from dbo.BusinessUnit_ChecklistItem (SELECTed by BusinessUnit and InUse).

I get a SQL exception stating that "Sub query returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the sub query follows follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I have attempted to modify the query to include an 'in' operator rather than a '=' operator, however that was not successful either. I may have done it incorrectly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkCurrentChecklistItemsAgainstInUseItems
        --Parameters
        @ECNID INT, --I need the ECNID to do the search properly.
        @BU NVARCHAR(50),
        @Date NVARCHAR(10), --This is the date that the checklist item was added to the ECN.
        @NewStatus NVarchar(3) --This is based off of the status of the ECN, will either be '?' or 'No'

    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @System NCHAR(6)='SYSTEM'
        DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(50) = 'This value was added by the system automatically.'--Not in use.

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ECN_ChecklistItem (ECNID, Required, LogBy, LogDate, Description, CheckName) 
VALUES(@ECNID, @NewStatus, @System, @Date, NULL, 
    (Select ChecklistItem FROM dbo.BusinessUnit_ChecklistItem WHERE BusinessUnit Like @BU
    EXCEPT SELECT CheckName FROM dbo.ECN_ChecklistItem WHERE ECNID Like @ECNID))

    END
    GO
```

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES` syntax will insert only one record in your table. Is this what you want? If so, make sure to select only one `CheckListItem` in your subquery, e.g. with a `TOP 1`. Otherwise you may want to use a different construct.

Comment: What do you want to do when your select statement returns more than 1 ChecklistItem?

Comment: I want to insert the ChecklistItem into the dbo.ECN_ChecklistItem table. It is possible that the SELECT EXCEPT query can return multiple values. Should I consider a different structure for handling this situation?

Comment: The best thing to do now is provide an example. This will greatly facilitate the discussion.

Comment: The currently used bridge table currently contains 6 values for a given ID.
Item 1
through
Item 6

The template table dbo.BusinessUnit_ChecklistItem may contain 8 values, in which case I will need to insert 2 values into the bridge table.

Comment: So yes, you will need to use an `INSERT ... SELECT` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the Insert Statement is towards a single row. However, the subquery might be returning (or has the possibility of returning) multiple rows. Whenever this situation occurs, SQL Server puts up this.

You might want to examine, by running the subquery separately as a query to find whether multiple rows are being returned even as you "assume" that there will be only row returned.

If it does indeed multiple rows, then you will need to handle that situation separately depending on your logic. 
However, if you are sure only one row is being returned, you can always a MAX or MIN or TOP 1 . Although they are inconsequential when a single row is being returned, they will avoid the 'subquery returned mutliple' error.

Edit : 
If you indeed want multiple rows to be inserted, replace the Values phrase, with the complete select phrase, with values for all the other fields remaining as fixed values (@ ones), and the value for CheckName coming from the select statement. Select @..., @..., @...., .... CheckListItem From .... Where BusinessUnit Like ... Except... and so on.

Comment: It is very possible that the SELECT EXCEPT statement can return multiple values. The majority of the use case is only 1 will be returned, but in the case of older records, it could return multiple values. In this case I will need to use all of the returned values. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want all the rows to be inserted ? If yes, replace the Values phrase, with the complete select phrase, with values for all the other fields remaining as fixed values (@ ones), and the value for CheckName coming from the select statement. Select @..., @..., @...., .... CheckListItem From .... Where  BusinessUnit Like ... Except... and so on.
If this is what you want and works for you, I could edit my answer to include this comment.

Comment: That worked exactly as intended. If you modify your answer to include that solution I will accept it.

Comment: Modified my answer to include info from my comment above.

Comment: Accepted as answer.